# Can't ping internally connected vm

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ping, ifconfig

I have three vms running with virtual box. 
 
The first one (VM1) has two network adapters set to:Internal network. Lets say the first adapter (eth19) is connected to internal network with name "int1" and the second adapter (eth20) is  connected to internal network with name "int2".
 
 
The second vm (VM2) has one network adapter( eth21 ) that is connected to internal network with name "int1" and finnally the third vm (VM3)  has one network adapter( eth25 ) that is connected to internal network with name "int2".

i set the ip addresses manually as following

```
(VM1): ifconfig eth19 10.0.0.1
       ifconfig eth20 10.0.0.10
output:
eth19 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e1:ad:2b  
      inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee1:ad2b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1259 (1.2 KiB)  TX bytes:10022 (9.7 KiB)

eth20 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e9:66:66  
      inet addr:10.0.0.10  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee9:6666/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5741 (5.6 KiB)  TX bytes:6775 (6.6 KiB)

 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
 10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth19
 10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth20


(VM2): ifconfig eth21 10.0.0.2

eth21 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:65:7b:83  
      inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe65:7b83/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:85 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:10002 (9.7 KiB)  TX bytes:7816 (7.6 KiB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth21



(VM3): ifconfig eth25 10.0.0.3

eth25 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ae:77:cd  
      inet addr:10.0.0.3  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feae:77cd/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:6303 (6.1 KiB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth25
```

i can ping from VM1 to VM2 and from VM2 to VM1 but i cant ping VM3.

ping from VM1 to VM3:

```
ping 10.0.0.3
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

what can be wrong?

EDIT
    arping VM1 to VM3

```
arping -I eth20 -c 2 10.0.0.3
ARPING 10.0.0.3
60 bytes from 08:00:27:ae:77:cd (10.0.0.3): index=0 time=667.000 usec
60 bytes from 08:00:27:ae:77:cd (10.0.0.3): index=1 time=448.000 usec

--- 10.0.0.3 statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received,   0% unanswered (0 extra)
```

arping VM1 to VM2

```
arping -I eth19 -c 2 10.0.0.2
ARPING 10.0.0.2
60 bytes from 08:00:27:65:7b:83 (10.0.0.2): index=0 time=330.000 usec
60 bytes from 08:00:27:65:7b:83 (10.0.0.2): index=1 time=622.000 usec

--- 10.0.0.2 statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received,   0% unanswered (0 extra)
```

Comment: Be sure that firewall in VM2 is off, because it will not work in ON mode. Setting the same IP to VM2 as VM1 is not a good idea because it causes a conflict.

Comment: its not firewall issue.actually VM3 is clone of VM2 so they have the same settings.I cant figure out the solution.Is kinda strange

Comment: Can you edit your post with the output of `ifconfig -a` and `route -n` for each of the hosts? Are you sure that the name of the internal network that `VM2` is connected to is indeed `int1`?

Comment: i just did Yoel.Yeah it is connected to the right internal network.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: You edited your question with the unreachable host to be `VM3` rather than `VM2`. Can you please verify that `VM3` is also connected to the correct internal network? Also, what's the content of the *`ARP` cache* on each of the hosts, right after you ping each of the other hosts? What happens when you [`arping`](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-arping.html) `VM3` from `VM1` and vice versa? Have you tried sending a *gratuitous `ARP` request* from `VM3`?

Comment: Yoel they are connected correctly.Strange thing is that when i connect VM3 to VM1 first, i can ping each other,and then when i connect VM2,it doesnt have connectivity and vice versa.So i can ping the VM that gets first ip address and not the other. Apring seems to work properly.

Comment: maybe i just figured it out.I think that when i try to reach a host wihtin the  10.0.0.0  network it always uses the first entry in routing table which is eth19 or eth20.so if i change the ip to VM2 for example ,into 10.0.1.2 and eth19 to 10.0.1.1 i can ping both VMs.but i dont know if thats what i need cause this makes 2 different networks.

Comment: Then leave the IP addresses of all interfaces as they initially were, except that of `eth20`, which may be modified since it lies in a different network anyway. Change it to `192.168.1.1` for example.

Comment: through eth20 in VM1 i can ping VM3 cause eth20 and eth25 in VM3 are internally connected.if i change the ip addressn to 192.168.1.1 i could not ping vm3.if i change eth25 ip to 192.168.1.2 i can ping all machines but this way i have to different networks.192.168.1.0 and 10.0.0.0.my goal is to have one network.i will try to use a virtual switch in VM1 and have eth19 and eth20 connected on it.

Comment: How come `eth20` and `eth25` are internally connected? Aren't they connected to different internal networks? If your goal is to have a single internal network, why are you defining two (`int1` and `int2`)?